# How can I put expression inside package.json string?

Tags: javascript, json, npm

**Question**:
How to increment version in script message? Because my release message should be always bigger to one version.

**Goal**: If I have already** 0.1.2 version**, I want to increment my **commit message to 0.1.3** and then release.
Of course I can always update it manually, but maybe some advices how to automate this process?

```
{
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "scripts": {
    "release": "git commit --allow-empty  -m \\\"chore: release 0.1.2\\\"",
```

So I need to take my current version, increment it and pass into release script, what I need to use to receive this result as I expect?

```
"scripts": {
    "release": "git commit --allow-empty  -m {expression}",
```

Comment: Why not use `npm version`, which will update the package file and make a commit?

Comment: JSON is just data, it doesn't execute code. You could use a script to create `package.json` and generate the expression dynamically.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have no experience with this package, I use github action for release which automatically update version

Comment: It's not a package, it's a command built right into the npm CLI: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-version?v=true

Comment: @Barmar Okay, I understand, I will try to generate json and then rewrite with new data, thank you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for advice, but I already use release-please action from google, which automatically do it, with some problems, that is reason why I need some tricky solution, because my gh action not work properly

Comment: Well you mentioned none of this in the question, which makes it very difficult to make sensible suggestions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Next time I will try describe problem more completely, thank you for the time! And good advice for use npm version, next project I will try it!

Comment: @Barmar can you post answer? I will mark it

Comment: If I had an answer I would post it.

Comment: @Barmar I found answer by myself, just want to upvote you, because you help me change mindset, I mean it is really good idea just write script for that. I found cool library which help work with json data. Generally I work only with Front-End and sometimes good to look around. 

Your phrase: "JSON is just data, it doesn't execute code. You could use a script to create" 

Was help me to change mindset, thank you man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [semver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver) in combination with a shell script to achieve your goal.

```
npm install -g semver
```

Create a shell script that will handle version incrementation and the Git commit.

you can try below Example script for testing (release.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

current_version=$(cat package.json | grep -o '"version": "[0-9.]\+"' | grep -o '[0-9.]\+')

new_version=$(semver bump patch $current_version)

git commit --allow-empty -m "chore: release $new_version"
```

Make sure the script is executable:

```
chmod +x release.sh
```

Update your "release" script in your package.json to call this shell script:

```
"scripts": {
  "release": "./release.sh"
}
```

Hope this helps and customize as needed.